# why does jquery not post correctly with codeigniter?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, function, post

I'm trying to post a variable to my php handler page, that tells php to ether add a certain form field's data to the database or not, but for some reason my post function will not post any thing. I am using the codeigniter framework, for the php side of things and jquery for the JavaScript side of things. I am thinking it may have to do with the URL I'm passing as the page to post to sense it's not a .php page or something like that, but I'm not sure. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
          $('form').submit(function() {
                if(new_gal) {
                    if(name_valid && description_valid && gal_name_valid && gal_description_valid) {
                    // return the new gal info to php
                      $.post('http://localhost/index.php/site/photoUploader', {NewGallerry: 'TRUE'}); 

                    return true;   
                }   else { 
                        return false;
                    } 
                } else if (name_valid && description_valid)
                {
                    // return the id of the gal to php and tell php not to add the info in the new gal section. 
                   $.post('http://localhost/index.php/site/photoUploader', {NewGallerry: 'FALSE'}); 
                   return true;    
                } else {
                    return false; 
                }
```

thank you so much to any one who spends the time attempting to answer this.

Comment: Use relative path. `/index.php/site/photoUploader`

Comment: Show your code in your `site` controller. Your jQuery code looks fine

Comment: @webarto: Why? Comments are much more useful if you explain something instead of just saying, do this.

Comment: @Juan Mendes, if it solves his problem I will then answer why. Currently it is pointless.

Comment: all im tring to do at the time being is just echo the posted data which is simple enough. I'm just using echo $this->input->post('NewGallerry'); so it should just be echoing out TRUE or FALSE. but I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: @webarto: What is pointless? To me, pointless is shouting out random things that aren't immediately obvious as to why you would do it.

Comment: @AlexW.H.B: Don't add comments, just update your question. Did you misspell `NewGallerry -> NewGallery` on both the client and server?

Comment: @Juan Mendes, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy, yeah, random..

Comment: well I just want to echo it so that i know that it's actually posting. I will end up using that info in my script later on, but in order to use it, it must be there. I do believe i misspelled both, because i just copied and pasted names.

Comment: @webarto: To people who aren't aware of the ins and outs of XHR's same origin policy, your comment looks random without an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
{'NewGallerry': FALSE}
```

instead of :

```
{NewGallerry: 'FALSE'}
```

anyway firebug console always helps you with ajax ;)

Comment: That should not be necessary, JavaScript objects doesn't need its properties to be quoted. jQuery properly quotes them when serializing them as JSON.

Comment: anyway firebug console always helps you with ajax ;) that is the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code uses localhost. Change it to your website. Javascript is executed solely on the client, not the server.

Comment: What if he's running it on his local machine? Thought about down voting because the part of the answer that says `Javascript is executed solely on the client, not the server` has nothing to do with the issue, even if the issue is cross domain problems.

Comment: I am running just a test server for the dev stages of the web site and that's why it is http://localhost/ but i will be moving the site to a web server as soon as it is done.